# Admin Backend Exact Match

Tags: magento2.2, grid, backend, magento2.2.7

In the admin backend on the order/customer grids we used to be able to do an exact search like, "Firstname" in Magento 2.2.5

This seems to no longer work in Magento 2.2.7. Is there a different/new way of doing an exact search now in the admin backend order or customer grids?

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same question i have looked everywhere and still not answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159397)